# Qual a diferença se eu instanciasse uma classe dentro do método ou se eu instanciasse só uma vez?

Tags: java, instanciar-objeto

Instância de uma classe cada vez que chamo o método:

```
 public String formatar(int valorFormatar){
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
   return df.format(valorFormatar);
 }
```

Agora um exemplo de fazer uma única instância da classe:

```
public class Formatar{
private int valor1;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");

    public String formatar(int valorFormatar){
       return df.format(valorFormatar);
    }
}
```

Eu tenho vários valores que quero formatar desse formato mas fiquei com dúvida de qual a melhor maneira de utilizar visto que para mim os dois dão resultado similar gostaria de saber a diferença e qual a forma correta para eu utilizar?

Comment: Na prática nada. A principal diferença é que se usar da primeira forma em 50 lugares e depois tiver que alterar o formato, vai precisar mudar nos 50 lugares. Claro que tem a questão deste objeto viver no escopo da classe ao invés do escopo do método na segunda forma, mas estou falando apenas da parte superficial.

Comment: Quando você utiliza o `new` dentro do método `formatar` você cria uma stack nova em memória a cada vez que executar o método, desta forma fica a cargo do garbage collector remover da memória esta instância nova quando não estiver mais em uso. Quando você utiliza a instância dentro da classe vc utiliza a mesma stack todas as vezes que executar o método `formatar`, economizando assim o uso de memória. Utilizando melhores práticas e otimização é mais recomendado utilizar a instância na mesma stack, ou seja dentro da classe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se instanciar localmente a variável certamente estará na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), o que é sempre desejável se não tiver um motivo para usar fora do método.

Se criar uma variável na classe ela ocupará espaço de memória no *heap* em toda instância dessa classe. Isso pode ser bom ou ruim.

A vantagem de criar na classe é que não precisará criar várias instâncias. Além de economizar no processamento da construção de um novo objeto evitará criar vários objetos no *heap*, o que diminui a pressão no *garbage collector*, que é algo bastante desejável. Se tiver que criar uma instância nova em cada método que precisa da formatação, vários objetos serão alocados, um para cada instanciação. Isso não costuma ser boa coisa.

Veja bem se vai instanciar `df` com `"###,###,###"` e nunca vai mudar, então não tem porque esta variável ser de instância. Faça dela uma variável estática e aí não consumirá espaço na instância dessa classe. Você terá um só objeto sem custos adicionais.

Se o método não vai acessar nenhum objeto da instância, o método pode ser estático também.

Se a classe for só isso e tende a ser chamada várias vezes eu faria assim:

```
public class Formatar {
    static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");

    public static String formatar(int valorFormatar) {
       return df.format(valorFormatar);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/FormatNumber.java).

Comment: E a desvantagem de criar a instância fora do método?

Comment: Depende de como precisa. Em geral é desvantagem sim, mas tem caso que não é, como demonstrei na resposta.